# How can I restore my audio, lost after an update

Tags: 20.04, gnome, sound

After a recent update to Ubuntu 20.04 my audio no longer produces any sound. I can't get any sound from any port on any device.

I have tried over a dozen suggestions found in Ask Ubuntu and I suspect at this point, I have only made matters worse. I now have two computers, both with the same problem.

Comment: "*I have tried over a dozen suggestions*" - Edit your question and include these details, especially if you think you made the problem worse. We need to know the current status of your device as well as any changes you've already made. Not only does this prevent us from reiterating obvious solutions and things you've already tried, but will help us advise you in case you need to revert something you already did

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

I gave up on trying to repair the audio as I had tried to follow so many suggestions that it seemed I was doing more harm than good. As a result, I restored my system from an earlier backup and my audio now works fine.